# How do I not create docker container logs?

Tags: logging, daemon, docker

So my Hard drive space filled up today after starting up a container as a daemon:

```
sudo docker run -d --name nexpose-server nexpose
```

After I found the logs file of my container I realised that running my container had spawned a **177GB log file** (all my free hard drive space).

I know this is not usual behaviour but the process in the container prints a lot of data to stdout. Most of the output is generated in the first 30 odd minutes as it updates itself initializes databases etc.

I would like to be able to either disable saving the logs or pipe the stdout to something like `/dev/null`. Is this possible? Has anyone got any better ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Starting from Docker 1.6 you can use `--log-driver=none` when you run your container. See examples here: https://www.sumologic.com/2015/04/16/new-docker-logging-drivers/

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
CMD while true ; do echo "hey"; sleep 1; done > /dev/null
```

See answer on the [docker lists](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/docker-user/TdtnPOFt9ZY/geiYo9sLjkMJ).

Comment: to quick was about to do this